# Execute code in Dynamics AX Workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it possible to execute X++ code as a step in an Ax Workflow?

So after an approval happens, some arbitrary code gets executed, then the workflow continutes?

eg

- Submit payment for approval.
- Payment is approved by Bill.
- Execute code that sends information about payment to another system
- Continue workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Ax uses events for this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc588240.aspx